# porque no puedo descargar un fichero excel en linux

Tags: php, symfony2

Estoy tratando de crear y descargar un fichero excel en php usando la libreria PHPExcel. 
La parte de crear el fichero va bien, pero a la hora de retornar para que se descargue en linux no me funciona en cambio en windows funciona perfecto.

```
    // We'll be outputting an excel file
    header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

    // It will be called file.xls
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.xls"');
    $objWriter = \PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter( $objPHPExcel, "Excel2007" );`introducir el código aquí`
    // Write file to the browser
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
```

En linux me da el siguiente error[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62035/discussion-on-question-by-alberto-cabrera-porque-no-puedo-descargar-un-fichero-e).

Comment: definitivamente el problema esta en la creacion del archivo temporal generado por la sentencia php://output, evidentemente no lo esta creando, por eso me dice que no encuentra el fichero

Answer (score 0):

creo que te faltan headers:

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Type: application/download");;
header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=$filename");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary ");
```